# Who controls the mind after fusion in DBZ?

Tags: dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball-series

In *Dragon Ball Z*, after fusion, who controls the mind and the body? Is it both or a single person?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are *several* types of fusion. For the majority of these, the more dominant/stronger individual controls the mind and body.

For Piccolo and Nail, they did the *Namekian Fusion*, Piccolo was the more dominant. There was also Cell and the Androids. Cell fused with them by a type of fusion called [*Absorption*](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Absorption). There was also the permanent fusion of Supreme Kai and his servant Kibito by using *The Potara Earrings*. Supreme Kai's personality was the one that stood out after that. For Dragon Ball Super we also see Kale and Caulifla fuse into Kefla who actually only seems to inherit Caulifla's personality.

In the normal fusion, the one you are more than likely asking about, the one that comes after initiating the [*Fusion Dance*](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Fusion_Dance). A new being is created from both individuals. [This being will..](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Fusion)

> combine both their attributes, from strength and speed to reflexes, intelligence and wisdom. When properly fused, the single being created has an astounding level of power, far beyond what either fusees would have had individually.

So, none of the fusees control the mind after the normal fusion. The being created after is a combination of both of their individual attributes and as such can think for itself.

Comment: Combing with the [Potara earings](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Potara) will yield a similar result, in terms of personality, as with the fusion dance

Comment: So who controls the body of GOTENKS?

Comment: @HariNandha Read the answer again. Gotenks is a completely different individual created from both of them. So, neither Trunks nor Gohan does.

Comment: @iKlsR You mean Goten, not Gohan. ;)

Comment: for the fusion dance, you can add that up to five people can fuse at once that way, so the new being is more adequate than a "dominant personality"

Comment: @gl_prout source?

Comment: You meant Kefura inherited Caulifla personality? Kale is shy, Caulifla and Kefura are carefree

Comment: @Pablo right, got them confused.

Comment: @iKlsR I can't recall correctly but I think it was explained by Goku when he was teaching it to the kids

Comment: @iKlsR it's even stated in the link in your answer that "More than two people can perform the fusion dance", just before the "God fusion" title

Answer (score 0):

It's a totally different person, e.g. x + y = z.

So it's not either one. Once they are fused, a new superpower being is formed.

If you remember what Trunks says to Pam when Goku and Vegeta are fused, he'll say that they both are not two different entity. They are one being :)

Comment: Welcome to Anime&Manga! Please consider editing your answer to include some more details, namely some sources for your info. Happy answering~

Answer (score 0):

Fusion dance = an entirely new being. And as far as the earrings go, it depends.

If one person is far more dominant in power and personality, then they remain who they are and are in complete control of the new form (old Kai and Kabito Kai), but if both fusee's are equal in power and dominance of personality, then similar to the dance, a new being completely will be created. You can tell if this occurs if you can hear both fusee's voices (Vegito).

Answer (score -1):

No one, once fused. He or she is an *entirely* different person, with a brand new personality and everything.

An exception *would* be the Namekian fusion.